# Why are cell name attributes undefined in my code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the code below. There are 4 visible elements here: 2 table cells, and 2 input text boxes. The last input text box displays the name of any of the first 3 elements clicked (the 2 cells and the first input box). Onclick of any of the first 3 elements will call the now() function with a "this" parameter (now(this)).
The now function then assigns the name of the clicked element to elemName variable, change the clicked element's background to blue, and make the value of the last text box to be assighened the elements name. Why is the cell name always undefined when anyone is clicked? Copy and try out the code. I need answers pls.

```html
<html>

<head>
<script>
 function now(elementa){
  elemName=elementa.name;
  elementa.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  document.getElementById("clickedElementName").value=elementa.name;
 } //end of now() function
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1" >
 <td name="cell1" onclick="now(this)">cell 1</td>
 <td name="cell2" onclick="now(this)">cell 2</td>
</table><br>

<input value=mdfkjkjei name="input" onclick="now(this)" type=text />
<br><br>

clicked elements name:<input id="clickedElementName" type=text />
</body>
</html>
```

when the cells are clicked, the last input text box is suppose to display its html name attribute, but it displays undefined. But when i click the first input text box it displays its name (input).
Why is the name of the table cells undefined.
Are table cells not allowed to have a name attribute in html?

Answer (score 3):

`td` elements have no `name` attribute, and consequently they have no `name` reflected property. If you use the `name` attribute (which is invalid), you can get its value via `getAttribute("name")`:

```
function now(elementa) {
  var elemName = elementa.getAttribute("name");                   // ***
  elementa.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  document.getElementById("clickedElementName").value = elemName; // ***
} //end of now() function
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function now(elementa) {
      var elemName = elementa.getAttribute("name");
      elementa.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      document.getElementById("clickedElementName").value = elemName;
    } //end of now() function
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <td name="cell1" onclick="now(this)">cell 1</td>
    <td name="cell2" onclick="now(this)">cell 2</td>
  </table><br>

  <input value=mdfkjkjei name="input" onclick="now(this)" type=text />
  <br><br> clicked elements name:<input id="clickedElementName" type=text />
</body>

</html>
```

*(Also note I declared the `elemName` variable, so you're not falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) [that's a post on my anemic little blog].)*

But if you're going to put non-standard attributes on elements, use the [`data-` prefix](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

```html
<td data-name="cell1" ..>
```

```js
function now(elementa) {
  var elemName = elementa.getAttribute("data-name"); // ***
  elementa.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  document.getElementById("clickedElementName").value = elemName;
} //end of now() function
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
  function now(elementa) {
    var elemName = elementa.getAttribute("data-name"); // ***
    elementa.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    document.getElementById("clickedElementName").value = elemName;
  } //end of now() function
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <td data-name="cell1" onclick="now(this)">cell 1</td>
    <td data-name="cell2" onclick="now(this)">cell 2</td>
  </table><br>

  <input value=mdfkjkjei name="input" onclick="now(this)" type=text />
  <br><br> clicked elements name:<input id="clickedElementName" type=text />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

user interaction element only have default name attribute like `input,select,button`.`td` not have that.so get the name via `getAttribute()` function in dom

```js
 function now(elementa){
  elemName=elementa.name;
  elementa.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  document.getElementById("clickedElementName").value=elementa.getAttribute('name');
 }
```

```html
<table border="1" >
 <td name="cell1" onclick="now(this)">cell 1</td>
 <td name="cell2" onclick="now(this)">cell 2</td>
</table><br>

<input value=mdfkjkjei name="input" onclick="now(this)" type=text />
<br><br>

clicked elements name:<input id="clickedElementName" type=text />
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks very much